# Updating colors dynamically using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to update the scene background dynamically using a npm package that's called 'react-colorful'.

So far it works great, debugging the color picker with `console.log()` returns desired colors but Three.js doesn't seem to update it when I change it using the hooks from React.

So my goal is to dynamically update the `scene.background` color when using the color picker. The color picker has no issues, returns everything dynamically when I debugged it.

Here is what I tried so far, if you need more information, feel free to ask.

My code is heavily based on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/WebSeed/pen/ZmXxKz)

```js
const ThreePromoKitAnim = () => {
  const [currBackground, setBackground] = useState('#ff0000')
  const mount = useRef()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // initialization of scene, camera
    mount.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  }, [])

  // value = returned color value from the color picker
  const handleBackgroundChange = (value) => {
    setBackground(value)
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(currBackground)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HexColorPicker
        color={currBackground}
        onChange={handleBackgroundChange}
     />
     <div className='threejs' ref={mount} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Also, I've noticed that when React auto updates the page (when saving code) and I set another value of the background color using the color picker it does work but not dynamically.

Am I missing something? Why doesn't the background change dynamically? How can I use hooks to dynamically change the background? Is there another workaround to dynamically change the color?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me, I just had to re-render the scene.

```js
  const handleBackgroundChange = useCallback((value) => {
    setBackground(value)
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(value)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }, [scene])
```

Comment: The difference is that you’re using `value` instead of `currBackground`. Even after you called `setBackground`, `currBackground` won’t change until the next time the component renders.